# JavaScript Flex communications

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex3

We currently have a JavaScript function which calls to Flex function as a callback reaction.

```
  JavaScript-->

  var newwindow;
  var me = document.getElementById("myApp");

  function getAreas(){
    thisMovie("swfID");
    me.setAreas("....");   
  }

  Flex-->

  public function setAreas(areas:String):void{...}
  ....
  public function init(){
         ExternalInterface.call("getAreas()");
  }
```

When we try to add another call to another JavaScript method is seems to fail.
To bypass the problem we are now using one method, although is there a problem with triggering two methods one after the other?

```
  For Example:

  Flex-->

  ExternalInterface.call("getAreas()");
  ExternalInterface.call("getUsers()");

  public function setUsers(areas:String):void{...} 

  JavaScript--> 

   function getUsers(){
    thisMovie("swfID");
    me.setUsers("....");   
  }
```

Comment: I don't know the details of flex but this could be browser specific.  Depending upon how flex hooks into the events, I believe some of the older methods could just have one call back.

Comment: Hi Pedz, you are raising an interesting point, it may well be limited to callback support. And I checked it on Chrome

Comment: From: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=events_02.html "When an event occurs, the object dispatches the event to all registered listeners by calling a function that was requested during registration" To me, this implies that you can have multiple listeners.

Comment: Even better, so my code should work properly, I wonder what is the issue?